# How to reach the current selected cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to change the accessory view type of a cell through the method: didSelectRowAtIndexPath , i.e. when a row is selected I want to change the accessory view type, can I do this inside that method ?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You can get the cell from *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method using the *indexPath* like this.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Comment: when I make [cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton] it has no effect on its accessory view using your solution, whats wrong ?

Comment: @JaHelia, Are you reloading the table view in *didSelectRowAtIndexPath:* method using `[tableView reloadData]`?

Comment: i think you have to save the indexpath somehow and then set the accessoryView in cellForRowAtIndexPath. Otherwise its overwritten everytime the tableview asks the delegate for the cells.

Comment: @JaHelia, Yes. You should do as @Tobi mentioned above, to make the cell show the accessory view even after you reload the table view

Comment: you can also use setNeedsLayout on the cell

Comment: for a collectionView use collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)

Answer (score 15):

**In Swift 3.0** : You can use these 2 ways, according to your need

```
 let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
```

**or**

```
let cell:CustomTableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
```

***Happy Coding !!***

Answer (score 6):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
     UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     // Access accessory View  as below.  
     UIView * myCellAccessoryView = myCell.accessoryView;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the below function and pass the index path of the selected row so that the particular cell is reloaded again.

```
- (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Another solution: store the selected row index and do a reload of tableview. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check for the selected row and change the accessory view of the cell.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift**

You can get the cell from didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method using the indexPath like this:

```
 let cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Answer (score 2):

Store selected indexpath. for eg: 
 NSInteger selectedIndexPath;
then follow the step below. set your accessory view.

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
    AddressTableViewCell *cell=(AddressTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

    Address *addr=[self.locationArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.titleLabel.text = addr.addressTitle;
    cell.detailLabel.text = addr.addressDetail;

        if (indexPath.row == selectedIndexPath) {
            [cell.selectButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxFilled"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        else {
            [cell.selectButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }

    return cell;
}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    selectedIndexPath=indexPath.row;

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```