# How to manage selected cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm building a blog reader app with a list of post objects in an NSArray.

```
cell.postTitle.text=post.Title;
```

I'm trying to find out which post has been selected and then set the corresponding `cell.postTitle.text` to a lighter font.

Somehow I have to remember this state when the navigationcontroller segue back to the top level (and destroyed?).

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this? Each post object has a postID. Maybe I can store this in NSUserDefault, but the list of read postID might grow too big over time.

Also there is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but in this method, I can't access the cell properties directly right?

Comment: I did [super tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] , that's why it was crashing. But I still have not been able to change the font.   `if ([self.readPost containsObject:post.PostId]) {
        cell.postTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:14];
    }
    
    cell.postTitle.text=post.Title;

    cell.subTitle.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i points by %@ %@", post.Points, post.Username, post.TimeCreatedString];
    return cell; `

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a UITableView to display your information you should use the delgate didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

In order to make this work with a custom interface (I assume you have), you should create your own custom cell, subclass UITableViewCell and create a controller and xib. You can then register your xib to the table and use that. Then you can call the needed attributes.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow I have to remember this state when the navigationcontroller segue back to the top level (and destroyed?).

This is best handled by using a delegate method by creating a custom protocol:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

When your user clicks the cell, you would call a delegate method which could set the postID value back in the top controller.

> Also there is didSelectRowAtIndexPath but in this method, I can't access the cell properties directly right?

Yes, you can get at the cell. Check out this question and answer:
[How to reach the current selected cell in didSelectRowAtIndexPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547065/how-to-reach-the-current-selected-cell-in-didselectrowatindexpath)

Alternatively, if you want to get at the data you used to create the table cells in the first place, in your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method you can used the `indexPath.row` value to get the value from your array that is at that index position and pass that via a delegate method.

Comment: Hey, I'm think I should add all the selected postID into an array and store it in NSUserDefault so this will be preserve between application shutdown. It's crashing right now for some reason.

Comment: What are you using to populate the UITableView?

Comment: Hey I fixed my problem. Thanks. The reason it was crashing was because I called super in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution.

Just add the `postId` of the selected post to an `NSMutableArray` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I check to make sure that the postID doesn't exist in my `self.readPostID` array.

If it does I set the font to Helvetica Light, else set it to Helvetica Bold.

First I had to make sure to `[self.tableview reloadData]` every time viewdidappear.

Second, I just save my NSMutableArray of readPostId to NSUserDefault everytime viewDidDisappear and reload the array in viewDidLoad.

Also I had to make sure that cell reuse doesn't affect the font. The else condition fixed that.