# How to get UITableViewCell object from indexPath in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm trying to get UITableViewCell object programmatically using Swift, so I wrote this code:

```
let cell:UITableViewCell = (UITableViewCell) UITableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath.row)
```

but getting compile error as:

> Cannot convert value of type '(UITableViewCell).Type' to specified type 'UITableViewCell'
>   Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
>   Instance member 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' cannot be used on type 'UITableView'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Comment: [possible duplicate of this please look up other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6547065/how-to-reach-the-current-selected-cell-in-didselectrowatindexpath)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

[`cellForRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) is not a class method. Use the instance method instead.

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Swift 3:

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` *does* take an index path as argument.

Comment: I am getting bad access in above code .  I am using custom cell here .

Comment: Got it . Actually heightForRowAtIndexPath is called before cellForRowAtIndexPath thats why i am getting issue .

Comment: @iThink, so what did you do? I have the same issue, I have to get the size of a cell's Label

Comment: Calculate the size *without* calling `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Is there any way to get the UITableViewCell type in the case of having two custom cell? I need to know which type of cell are returned on this index path. What would be the best approach to get the type?

Comment: There is the operator `is` in Swift to check a type, such as `cell is CustomCell`.

Answer (score 41):

You can use this for **Swift 4**

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 7):

Swift 5 Easy solution

```
//MARK:- Collection View
let cell = yourcollectionview.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! YourCollectionViewCell
```

Table View

```
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
```

Usage

```
let tempImage = cell.yourImageView.image!
```

Answer (score 6):

First get row number where you want to go then call below code.

```swift
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: rowNumber, section: 0)
let tableViewCell = YourTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent it from getting crashed use `if let` condition as follows...

```
 if let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)) as? MyTableCell {
         // do stuff here
     cell.updateValues(someValues)
 }
```

also can fetch headerView as follows...

```
if let headerView = myTableView.headerView(forSection: 0) as? MyHeaderView {
//do something
}
```